# How to convert List<List<int>> to an array of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

What is the best way to convert a list into an array of type `int[][]`?

```
List<List<int>> lst = new List<List<int>>();
```

Comment: Technically, an `int[][]` isn't a multidimensional array (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.71).aspx), but rather an array of arrays.

Comment: Array of type `int[][]` is not a multidimensional array, it's just an array of arrays. Two-dimensional array would be `int[,]`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: also known as Jagged Arrays http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: `int[][]` certainly has 2 dimensions. The correct naming depends a little on context.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
int[][] arrays = lst.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: You could just use `lst.Select(Enumerable.ToArray).ToArray()`

Comment: What if we need to assign in `int[,] arrays`? Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you could do something like

var list = new List<List<object>>();
object[,] array = new object[N, M];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
                    array[i, j] = list[i][j];

and you will have an `object[,]` where N and M are the dimensions of the outer and inner list respectively

Comment: @ShekharRai - Not super easy to map a jagged list to a 2D array.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy with LINQ:

```
lst.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToArray()
```

If you really wanted two-dimentional array (`int[,]`, not `int[][]`), that would be more difficult and the best solution would probably be using nested `for`s.

Comment: Almost 6 years later, I guess if I want int[,], there is no other way than to run explicit loops?

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it using linq.

```
int[][] arrays = lst.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

but if you want another way you can loop through the list and manually generate the 2d array.

[how to loop through nested list](http://www.dotnetperls.com/nested-list)

Answer (score -1):

There's no library function to do this.

You'll need to do this with loops.

```
int[][] newlist = new int[lst.Size][];
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Size; i++)
{
    List<int> sublist = lst.ElementAt(i);
    newlist[i] = new int[sublis.Size];
    for (int j = 0; j < sublist.Size; j++)
    {
        newlist[i][j] = sublist.ElementAt(j);
    }
}
```

There you go!

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have any restriction on using `List<int[]>` instead of `List<List<int>>` than use `List<int[]>` and then convert it into array of array using `.ToArray()` at end of list object.

Example for first converting `List<List<int>>` to  `List<int[]>`

```
    List<int[]> listOfArray=new List<int[]>();
    List<List<int>> yourList=[someValue];
    foreach(var listItem in yourList){
        listOfArray.Add(listItem.ToArray());
    }
```

Example For `List<int[]>` to  `int[][]`:

```
  int[][] jaggedArray= listOfArray.ToArray(); //voila you get jagged array or array of array
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's clearly `List<List<int>>`. You can't just answer a "similar" question.

Comment: Yahh you are right!, the solution for this question were already explored and given by other users, so that is why I tried to give some other alternate way to get to the answer. Any way thanks for pointing that out, if it isnt helpful to anyone  i will remove the answer.

Comment: It's an alternative question you're answering. This doesn't answer the actual question that was asked. Had you shown how to get from a `List<List<int>>` to a `List<int[]>` then you may have been on to something.