# Append two multidimensional arrays object [,]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to work with multidimensional arrays. I have two object [,] which I would like to append. After looking up this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238355/how-to-convert-listlistint-to-multidimensional-array), I tried adding the arrays to a `List<object[,]>` and then tried converting it to an array, but without success. Is there a proper way to do this or a helper method that can append these arrays for me?

My code is below:

```
Worksheet sheet1 = (Worksheet)workBookIn.Sheets[ 1 ];
Worksheet sheet2 = (Worksheet)workBookIn.Sheets[ 2 ];

Range excelRange1 = sheet1.UsedRange;
Range excelRange2 = sheet2.UsedRange;

object[,] arr1 = (object[,])excelRange1.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
object[,] arr2 = (object[,])excelRange2.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

List<object[,]> records = new List<object[,]>();
records.Add(arr1);
records.Add(arr2);

object[,] result = records.Select(a => a.ToArray()).ToArray(); // <-- Does not work
```

Comment: In general Linq doesn't work well with multidementional arrays.  Also exactly how do you want to append one to the other.  I mean it only makes sense if they are similar dimensions, but if one in 3x2 and the other is 5x4 what would you do?  And if they have the same dimensions like both are 4x4 is the result 4x8 or 8x4?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```
static void AddToArray<T>(T[, ] result, T[, ] array, int start = 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); ++j)
            result[i + start, j] = array[i, j];
}
```

**Usage**

```
int d1 = arr1.GetLength(0) + arr2.GetLength(0);
int d2 = arr1.GetLength(1) > arr2.GetLength(1) ? arr1.GetLength(1) : arr2.GetLength(1);

object[, ] result = new object[d1, d2];

AddToArray(result, arr1);
AddToArray(result, arr2, arr1.GetLength(0));
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kWk9sI)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you're trying to read from an Excel Worksheet using Excel VSTO (Visual Studio Tools For Excel). Here is a different way to process data from Excel

```
object[,] sheetData =  excelRange1.Value2;
```

This will fill your array with data based on the size of the range, instantly. It is faster than reading individual values, since it only makes a single call to the interop tools, which are slow. The only thing to note is that it returns a 1 indexed array! There is no value at 0, 0, and attempting to access it throws IndexOutOfBounds.

Of course you can go the other way.

```
excelRange1.Value2 = processedData;
```

This will fill that range with the data from the array. If the range is larger or smaller than the array, no problem, it will just fill as much as it can and put "#DATA" in cells with no definition in the array.

Once you have the `sheetData` array, it should be easy enough to fill a DataTable with that information, and then run your queries or processing on that. This is what that would look like. Hope it helps!

```
object[,] sheetData = range.Value2;
DataTable table = new DataTable();

//Add columns
for (int i = 1; i < sheetData.GetLength(1) + 1; i++)
{
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn("Column-" + i, typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(column);
}

//Add all rows and data within each row. 
for (int i =  1; i < sheetData.GetLength(0) + 1; i++)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    for (int j = 1; j < sheetData.GetLength(1) + 1; j++)
        row[j - 1] = sheetData[i, j];
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```